# windows batch / multiple commands per line

Tags: c, windows, batch-file, cmd

I use Windows and I have a C program which calls `popen` to execute a command dynamically.

But if i try to execute something like this:

```
set a=10
echo %a%
```

it doesnt work.

I tried (manually) to save the command as the following C strings:

- `set a=10&echo %a%` => Output: `%a%`
- `set a=10\necho %a%` => Output: `""` (empty)
- `set a=10\r\necho %a%\r\n` => Output: `""` (empty)

It should output "10". How can I do this?

Comment: What program is `popen()` opening?  Can we see your code?

Answer (score 1):

you mean execute a DOS command dynamically? you could try something like

```
%systemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe \c set a=10&echo%a%
```